# Numeric test when using the conditional operator

Tags: bash

In bash, why doesn't this work:

```
$ echo $((1 -gt 2 ? 3 : 4))
bash: 1 -gt 2 ? 3 : 4: syntax error in expression (error token is "2 ? 3 : 4")
```

Neither does this:

```
$ echo $(((1 -gt 2) ? 3 : 4))
bash: (1 -gt 2) ? 3 : 4: missing `)' (error token is "2) ? 3 : 4")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
if [ 1 -gt 2 ]; then
  echo 3
else 
  echo 4
fi
```

Or:

```
echo $((2 > 1 ? 1 : 0))
```

The -gt family is used by the [test command](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/test.html), while the operators allowed in $(()) are described [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap01.html#tag_01_07_02_01) and [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04).  You can't mix and match.

Note from the standard that "only signed long integer arithmetic is required."  You need to use bc.

Comment: Because bash doesn't support floating point.  Use the bc command.